# c# Close a form opened from and instance class from the main form that created the class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a difficulty in sizing my form!

I dynamically create buttons on a form and need to know if they are all fully visible or if I need to grow the form and in what direction to make all the buttons fully visible.

I don't want to use the autosize property as I need to control the layout.

So how do I tell if a dynamically created controls bounds are within that of the form?

thanks

This a .Net 4 classic forms app.

Comment: you should retitle this question to match what you are asking, the title and the question are completely disjointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the button to the controls collection, to see if it is visible check the contains on the forms bounds - `Form.Bounds.Contains(button.Bounds));`.  If that returns false then you need grow your form. Here is some basic code to do the form growing, it will not necessarily produce the prettiest output and is not necessarily the best way, just written to give you a quick idea of how it could be accomplished.

```
// Add the control
form.Controls.Add(button);
var formBounds = form.Bounds;
var controlBounds = button.Bounds;
if (!formBounds.Contains(controlBounds))
{
    formBounds.Left = Math.Min(controlBounds.Left, formBounds.Left);
    formBounds.Right = Math.Max(controlBounds.Right, formBounds.Right);
    // Do similar for top and bottom this will ensure your button is visible
    form.Bounds = formBounds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the button, can't you compare the Width of the container vs the Left + Width properties of the newly added button?

Comment: I wasn't even attempting to provide an explicit implementation...just a high level solution.